# Why is this method right to solve some equations of degree 2?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given this equation

$-x^2+x+6=4$

We can write it as

$(3-x)(x+2) = 4$

So weridly if I take
$(3-x) = 4$ and $(x+2) = 4$, I can get $x=-1$ and $x=2$ that are indeed the correct solutions.

Why does this happen? And in which cases can this occur?

Comment: It only works because in those cases the other factor cancels out to $1$, which makes no difference. This doesn't work in general- it works exactly if the other factor goes to $1$ upon substitution of the value you get.

Comment: In short, it happens because it is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(a-x)(x-b) = c$

With roots $r_1$ and $r_2$.

We need four equalities to be true

$$a-r_1 = c, \quad r_1-b = 1, \quad a-r_2 = 1, \quad r_2-b = c$$

We get

$$\text{$r_1=a-c=b+1$ and $r_2=a-1 = b+c$}$$

Which implies $c=a-b-1$

So for any $a$ and $b$

$$(a-x)(x-b) = a-b-1$$

will behave as you described.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the given equation can be rewritten as

$$(x+1)(x-2)=-[(3-x)-4][(x+2)-4]=0$$

which leads to $3-x=4$ and $x+2=4$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because in both of the solutions one of the parts of the product become a "1". I mean, for example, when you look for the solution and you write $(3-x)=4$ you are asuming $x+2=1$ so $x=-1$ which is in fact a valid solution for the equation. An the same occurs in the other case.
I will have to give it a deeper thought but I think that with that it may be possible to findd out more examples.